# Caffe Compilation Error - Ubuntu 18.04.4 Live Server in a Virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, caffe, ubuntu-18.04

What does this error mean, during [caffe](https://github.com/tianzhi0549/CTPN) compilation ? How shall I fix it?

Commands:

```
cd /home/aegono/CTPN/caffe
sudo make
```

Output:

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgflahs
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_serial_h1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:515: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1/CTPN/caffe
```

UPDATE :

I already installed the modules but I do not know how to link them and what files shall be linked and where shall I find them. I tried the command below with no luck. Am I doing the right thing?

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100.0.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5_serial_h1
```

UPDATE:
     `/home/aegono/CTPN/caffe` is the location of my caffe package.
     In `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` when I look for the word `gflahs`, I could not find anything but when I look for the word `gflags` using the command `ls -l | grep 'gflags'` , below are the results :

```
root@ubuntu_18-04-4_live_server:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls -l | grep "gflags"
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   258068 Aug  6  2017 libgflags.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   256002 Aug  6  2017 libgflags_nothreads.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       26 Aug  6  2017 libgflags_nothreads.so -> 
libgflags_nothreads.so.2.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Aug  6  2017 libgflags_nothreads.so.2.2 -> 
libgflags_nothreads.so.2.2.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   146096 Aug  6  2017 libgflags_nothreads.so.2.2.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       16 Aug  6  2017 libgflags.so -> 
libgflags.so.2.2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       18 Aug  6  2017 libgflags.so.2.2 -> 
libgflags.so.2.2.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   150248 Aug  6  2017 libgflags.so.2.2.1
```

And when I look for `hdf5` using the command `ls -l | grep 'hdf5_serial'`, below are the result:

```
root@ubuntu_18-04-4_live_server:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls -l | grep "hdf5_serial"
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       54 Mar 24 06:01 hdf5_serial_h1 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       54 Mar 24 06:22 hdf5_serial_h1.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       54 Mar 23 19:22 lhdf5_serial_h1 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8028880 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   398412 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial_fortran.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       33 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial_fortran.so -> libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.100.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       33 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.100 -> libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.100.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   250760 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial_fortran.so.100.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   245840 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial_hl.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   187354 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       35 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so -> libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.100.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       35 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.100 -> libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.100.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   121400 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serialhl_fortran.so.100.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial_hl.so -> libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       28 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100 -> libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   138576 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial_hl.so.100.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     4084 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial.settings
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial.so -> libhdf5_serial.so.100.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       25 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial.so.100 -> libhdf5_serial.so.100.0.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  3495976 Aug 13  2017 libhdf5_serial.so.100.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       51 Mar 23 19:17 libhdf5.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial.so.100.0.1
```

Comment: You are missing `hdf5_serial` and `gflags`.

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf  -> Installed them already.

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf  - Is it really gflags? Why does my error says "gflahs"

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `hdf5_serial` and `gflags` according to the compilation error. Try installing them using `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev`.

If you have them already installed, you need to link them.

**Edit:**
Goto the `Makefile.config`. Perform the following changes to the `PYTHON_INCLUDE`, `INCLUDE_DIRS`, and `LIBRARY_DIRS`

```
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include  
WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1  
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial  
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
```

Comment: Is it really gflags? Why does my error says "gflahs"

Comment: `glfags` is required by caffe. Don't know about `gflahs`. Please see updated answer for linking `hdf5_serial`.